# Cohomology from homology with coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The usual presentation of the coboundary map $\delta: \Delta^i(X;G)\to\Delta^{i+1}(X;G)$ is that it is the dual map of the boundary homomorphism $\partial: \Delta_{i+1}(X)\to\Delta_i(X)$. (Hatcher)

In Hatcher, the chain group $\Delta_i(X)$ is taken to be  free abelian with basis the $i$-simplices of $X$.

Can we consider more general $\Delta_i(X)$ with coefficients, say in another abelian group $H$? How will that change things, and how will the coefficients $H$ "interact" with the coefficients $G$?

For instance, if $c$ is a $n+1$-chain (with coefficients in $H$), and $\phi$ is a $n+1$-cohain, then is $\delta\phi(c)$ well-defined? Using the usual formula will give a linear combination of terms in $G$ with coefficients in $H$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\hom_\mathbb Z(\Delta(X)\otimes H,G) = \hom_\mathbb Z(\Delta(X),\hom(H,G))$ by adjunction.

Comment: May I ask what does $hom_\mathbb{Z}$ mean? Group homomorphisms? Thanks.

Comment: Abelian group homomorphisms.